# Email signature question

Tags: email, credentials

I have 3 Associate in Applied Science Degrees (Accounting, Legal Secretary, and Information Processing) and also a Microsoft Office Specialist (MOS) certification. How can I properly acknowledge my degrees and certification in my professional email signature?

Comment: Why did you not include your country and where you need this signature (private, working in Academia, working as taxi driver, working as politician,..)?

Comment: You did edit your question, but did not provide the country and not the profession.

Comment: Just sign with your name.

Comment: @henning--reinistateMonica: This does not "acknowledge my degrees".

Comment: In the U.S., degrees below the doctorate are generally not listed at all.  Doctorates, other than the MD degree, are generally not used outside academia.  Also, do not confuse "certification" with a degree.  They are distinctly not the same.

Comment: I should add to my earlier comment that, in the U.S., you do sometimes see masters-level degrees listed when they are a professional qualification, for example, MSW in social work, or M.Ed. in education.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not include said information for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I properly acknowledge my degrees and certification in my professional email signature?

```
Name, BSc, MSc, MOS
```

Where BSc and MSc are the titles of your degrees. (I'm unsure what the third title might be.) Alternatively, just list the highest academic degree:

```
Name, MSc, MOS
```

Or, just don't mention them:

```
Name
```

Comment: I don't think "Mos" is a title.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica It's the one given by the OP. (Admittedly, I got the case wrong initially.)

Comment: yes, but OP is wrong. ;)

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica so should the answer be down-voted due to the OP's error?

Comment: @Solar Mike not sure, didn't vote.

Comment: MOS is a certification